# c# unity2d: How can I move an Object and to change the direction when it collides?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The Object moves, but it doesn't change its direction and i don't know why.

**Thats the code for the object named 'zackenblock':**

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class zackenblock_move : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static bool col = false;
    public float speed = 10f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (zackenblock_col.collosin != col)
        {
            col = zackenblock_col.collosin;
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (col == false){
            transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * speed);
        }
        else
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.left * Time.deltaTime * speed);
        }

        /*if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.M))
        {
            col = true;
        }*/
    }
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision){
        //Check for a match with the specified name on any GameObject that collides with your GameObject
        if (collision.gameObject.name == "Level1_part2")
        {
            //If the GameObject's name matches the one you suggest, output this message in the console
            Debug.Log("Do something here");
            col = true;
        }

        else if (collision.gameObject.name == "Level")
        {
            //If the GameObject's name matches the one you suggest, output this message in the console
            Debug.Log("Do something here");
            col = false;
        }
    }
    /*IEnumerator waiter_not_that_waiter_just_waiter(){
        yield return new waitforseconds(3f);
        //my code here after 3 seconds
        transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime);
        yield return new waitforseconds(3f);
        transform.Translate(Vector3.left * Time.deltaTime);
    }*/

}
```

**And thats the code from the tilemap:**

```cs
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class zackenblock_col : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static bool collosin;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.M))
        {
            collosin = true;
        }
    }
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision){
        //Check for a match with the specified name on any GameObject that collides with your GameObject
        if (collision.gameObject.name == "zackenblock")
        {
            //If the GameObject's name matches the one you suggest, output this message in the console
            Debug.Log("Do something here");
            collosin = true;
        }

        /*else if (collision.gameObject.name == "Level")
        {
            //If the GameObject's name matches the one you suggest, output this message in the console
            Debug.Log("Do something here");
            collosin = false;
        }*/
    }
}
```

Here are some screenshots:

Screenshot of unity and the object:[image]

Screenshot of unity and the tilemap:[image]

Screenshot of unity and the tilemap2:[image]

The object should move to right and when it collides then move left.

It only moves right non-stop.

Comment: Hi - could you reformat your question a bit, you should include the code in the question using code block markup, and with commented out code removed. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for extra info

Comment: You might wanna look at Physic Materials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The major problem with your code is that you are misspelling. Change 'collosin' into 'collision'. And change:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
```

into

```
void OnCollisionEnter2d(Collision2d collision)
```

Other than that it seems like your code is fine.

Comment: I am so happy it helped, please consider upvoting so more people can see it @MarcUs7

Answer (score 0):

Use OnCollisionEnter2D because you are making a 2D game

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
        {
           
        }
```

also check out OnCollisionStay2D/exit if the collisions tend to stick .